# Допустимы ли искажения названий при переводах?

Tags: переводы

Я не раз уже сталкивался с тем, что в официальных переводах иностранных фильмов искажаются имена и названия. Причем, делается это без всякой видимой причины. Особенно отличаются этим переводы телеканала СТС. Однажды, когда я наткнулся на фильм, который до этого смотрел всегда с любительскими субтитрами, где ни имена не искажали, ни оригинальную речь не глушили, то просто, как говорится, выпал в осадок.
Мне было бы интересно узнать, допустимы ли искажения имен собственных в переводах и, если да, то в каких случаях?
Слушай благозвучности (как, например, в переводе книг Р. Сальваторе, где главного героя зовут Drizzt, но перевели как Дзирт) опустим, это и так понятно.

Comment: Опечатка ли — «слушай», если Ч и Ш в косой сажени друг от друга?

Answer (score 4):

Хотелось бы увидеть примеры некорректного, по вашему мнению, перевода. Без них 
понять логику локализаторов невозможно. Вообще имена собственные чаще 
всего изменяют (уберем вариант, где одно и тоже имя можно писать по разному: *Ватсон-Уотсон*) в следующих случаях:

1. Неблагозвучность или труднопроизносимость.
2. "Говорящие" имена или фамилии.
3. Уже сложившаяся традиция произнесения имени.
4. Другое смысловое значение, чем в языке оригинале (при локализации 
   игр в жанре фэнтези славянские имена для создания атмосферы при 
   переводе иногда латинизируют).

---

Предположу, что в случае из комментария мы имеем дело с двойным переводом. Кто-то перевел с японского на английский, а уже с английского перевели на русский.

Comment: Есть, например, очень хороший аниме-сериал "Бродяга Кеншин" (исторический, серьезный и умный). Но дело не в этом, а в том, что там практически все имена просто исказили. Кеншин (или по Поливанову - Кенсин) стал Кенси, Яхико - Ёси, Каору - Кори и т.д. Я не вижу тут никакого логического объяснения, кроме дури переводчиков канала СТС.  
И это только один пример, коих немало.

Answer (score 1):

Перевод текста на иной язык есть предмет договора между правообладателем и переводчиком. Высеченных в камне законов нет. 
В киномире особенно. Компания называет товар так, как он звучит благозвучно и влияет на продажи. Это почти всегда с лекарствами, популярной едой.  
Если русский прокат покупает право на показ амер. фильма, то контракт может разрешить изменения названия, имён героев на русский лад или по причине неблагозвучия, и даже переделку и обрезку и вставку монтажа.

Answer (score 0):

Локализация текста или звукового ряда - это не совсем ТОЛЬКО ПЕРЕВОД. Это именно локализация. Практикуется практических во всех странах. Когда я совсем ничего не знал о локализации, то думал, что речь идёт лишь о неудачном переводе, но ошибался. Изменения бывают порой настолько сильными, что по локальному названию бывает порой просто невозможно догадаться (обратный перевод) о том, как же фильм называется в оригинале.